# Add internal padding to text widget on only one side

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

So in my program I have a text widget and I want to add padding between the actual text and the side of the widget, but only on one side. You can do it on both sides by declaring the `padx` when the widget is being created. This is my code so far:

```
inputEntry = Text(bd=0, bg="#d9d9d9", highlightthickness=0, font='calibri', pady=10)
```

I would like to also add `padx` to only one side of the text widget (The right side). I tried `padx=(0, 20)` but it didn't work. Is there anything that can do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is all of my code:

```
inputEntryImg = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("inputEntry.png"))
inputEntryBg = mainWindowCanvas.create_image(400.0, 168.5, image=inputEntryImg)
inputEntry = Text(mainWindow, bd=0, bg="#d9d9d9", highlightthickness=0, font='calibri')
inputEntryScroll = Scrollbar(inputEntry)
inputEntry.configure(yscrollcommand=inputEntryScroll.set)
inputEntry.pack(side=LEFT)
inputEntryScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
inputEntry.place(x=41.0, y=83, width=718.0, height=169)
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. If you have another question you need help with, ask a new one. This makes questions useful for others too.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I don't believe I asked two questions...which ones are separate questions?

Comment: *I tried it in a separate project and it worked, so Im not sure what could be causing it. I'll edit the question to show the rest of the code, as I have also put a scrollbar and some other stuff into it.* is a following questions to your existing. Don't you agree?

Comment: They wanted to know why it wasn't working and if there was any other code that affected it so I showed them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the text widget inside a frame and add the required padding when using the layout function:

```py
inputFrame = Frame(bg='#d9d9d9')
inputFrame.pack()
inputEntry = Text(inputFrame, bd=0, bg='#d9d9d9', highlightthickness=0, font='calibri')
inputEntry.pack(padx=(0,10), pady=10)
```

Note that it is recommended to specify the parent of widget when creating the widget.

Comment: `bd` and `highlightthickness` is 0 by default for `Text` widget.

Comment: @Thingamabobs No `bd` is not 0 by default for a `Text` widget. BTW it is just a copy from OP's code.

Comment: Thankyou for helping! Unfortunately I can not type in the widget after doing this.

Comment: @Joshilovessnow It works fine for me.  There should be something else causing your problem.

Comment: I tried it in a separate project and it worked, so Im not sure what could be causing it. I'll edit the question to show the rest of the code, as I have also put a scrollbar and some other stuff into it.

Comment: @acw1668 I edited the question, could you have a look?

Comment: @acw1668 maybe it doesn't work when I set the bg to photo image?

Comment: @Joshilovessnow It maybe caused by packing the scrollbar into the text widget.

Comment: @acw1668 so how do I put the scrollbar there? Do I put it in the frame?

Comment: Try putting it in the same frame of the text widget.

Comment: @acw1668 it doesn't work, the text widget is still locked and the scrollbar is above it instead of to the right

Comment: If you put both text and scrollbar widgets in he same frame, it should work.